# custom google search increase number of results

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

I was wandering if anyone had figured out a way to increase the number of results to more then 10, when using the custom google search engine? I know you can reset the starting point to 11, then 21, and so on, but that isn't an option since I have 1,620 results to go through and only 100 searches per day.

Answer (score 1):

Not technically a programming question - as this is changed in your CSE console.

The hard limit you can get per page is 20 results. Anything higher and you'll need to use Google's advanced search.

You'll find the setting here:

[image: Increase CSE results number]

Comment: Yes I had changed that before but the query still only returns 10 items and not 20. Is there something else I am forgetting to change?

Comment: Did you find solution @DennisOakdale ?